# Images not showing in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, png

I have an unordered list with image links and when you hover over them they fade out a little bit and this shows all good in every browser except IE, of course. At first I thought it was just a png bug but after applying both of those fixes it still doesn't work. The page is at:

[The page.](http://dev.greensports.org)

If anyone knows what is going on please let me know as I am completely stumped now. Thanks

Comment: Please expand on what the problem is exactly, and in what IE versions (IE8 shows no images at all, for instance). Also, you only use webkit-specific transitions, so the transition won't work in FF either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to work in IE7 and IE9, but not IE8. Interested, never seen that before.

Anyway, you can fix the problem by using a different method. Instead of using a list, just have your images (with links) inside the containing `<div>`, then apply a style to the links such that they have `display: inline-block;` - this will allow you to align them vertically with each other (`vertical-align: middle;`) and set their width if you want.

Answer (score 1):

The opacity fade is being achieved by styles that IE doesn't support

```
-webkit-transition: opacity;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
-webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
```

Comment: Well I thought this for a second but remembered that IE just ignores those styles and displays the images as is.

Comment: I thought the issue here was that the transition effect wasn't shown in IE? Glad you got your issue sorted either way :)

Answer (score 0):

It works in IE9 so first guess is you are using some css or javascript that isn't supported for earlier versions.   You need to post the code so we can give you better guidance on how to resolve this.